# How to disable UIBarButtonItem based on tag in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I had created button in toolbar and set tag to it. I had declared that button locally. Now in some other function I want to disable the button as per condition.

Is there any way to disable UIBarButton based on tag without declaring the button globally.

```
****************************************************
     func setToolBar()
        {
            let toolbar : UIToolbar = UIToolbar()
            toolbar.sizeToFit()

            let prevButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "<", style: .Plain, target: self, action:"goBack:")
            prevButton.tag = 20

           let nextButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: ">", style: .Plain, target: self, action:"goNext:")
            nextButton.tag = 30

            let flexButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)

            let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Plain, target: self, action:"done:")

            let arrItems : NSArray = [prevButton , nextButton,flexButton, doneButton]
            [toolbar.setItems(arrItems as? [UIBarButtonItem], animated: true)]
            city.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
            birthdate.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        }

****************************************************

 func goBack(sender: UIBarButtonItem)
    {
        let prevTag : NSInteger = CurrentTextFiled.tag - 1

        let nextResponder = CurrentTextFiled.superview?.viewWithTag(prevTag)

        if((nextResponder) != nil)
        {
            nextResponder!.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        else
        {
           //Disable UIBarButton here with tag 20
        }
    }

****************************************************

    func goNext(sender: UIBarButtonItem)
    {
        let prevTag : NSInteger = CurrentTextFiled.tag + 1
        let nextResponder = CurrentTextFiled.superview?.viewWithTag(prevTag)

        if((nextResponder) != nil)
        {
            nextResponder!.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        else
        {
           //Disable UIBarButton here with tag 30
        }
    }
```

---

Comment: It looks to me like you would have to assign a tag to the UIToolBar you are adding those buttons to. When you want to enable/disable a button, use viewWithTag() as shown below to find the toolbar, and then traverse the toolbar's UIBarButtonItem array (items property) to find the button you want by checking its tag.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I distilled this down to a code snippet that can be run inside a playground, and verified this within Xcode.

In essence, you want to give a tag to the toolbar and find it with viewWithTag().  Once you have the toolbar, traverse thru its items array and filter out the button you want to manipulate.  Don't forget to add the toolbar to your viewController's view as a subview.

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
   self.setToolBar()
   self.disableButton(20)
}

func setToolBar()
{
    let toolbar : UIToolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.tag = 10
    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    self.view.addSubview(toolbar)  //must add to subview of viewcontroller

    let prevButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "<", style: .Plain, target: self, action:"goBack:")
    prevButton.tag = 20

    let nextButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: ">", style: .Plain, target: self, action:"goNext:")
    nextButton.tag = 30

    let flexButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)

    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Plain, target: self, action:"done:")

    let arrItems : NSArray = [prevButton, nextButton,flexButton, doneButton]
    [toolbar.setItems(arrItems as? [UIBarButtonItem], animated: true)]
    print("Toolbar set.")
}

func disableButton(tag: Int)
{
    if let toolbarWithButtons = self.view.viewWithTag(10) as? UIToolbar {
        print("Toolbar found by tag. Trying to disable button with tag \(tag).")
        var buttonToDisable: Array<AnyObject>?
        if let buttons = toolbarWithButtons.items {
            buttonToDisable = buttons.filter({
                (x : AnyObject) -> Bool in

                if let button = x as? UIBarButtonItem {
                    if button.tag == tag {
                        return true
                    }
                }
                return false
            })

            if let button = (buttonToDisable!.first as? UIBarButtonItem){
                button.enabled = false
                print("Button with tag \(button.tag) enabled: \(button.enabled)")
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        print("Toolbar not found by tag.")
    }
}

}


var ctrl = MyViewController()

XCPShowView("Playground VC", ctrl.view)
```

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: App crash in this line ******let buttonToDisable = toolbarWithButtons.items?.filter({****** fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: I updated to code snippet so that it can be run inside a playground.

Comment: I can't add toolbar in main view. I have to add tool bar as a inputAccessoryView of textfiled

Comment: Since you are setting your toolbar as the inputAccessoryView of city and brithdate, just alter the disableButton function to get a reference to the toolbars you need to disable the button in.

Answer (score 2):

You can get view a using tag.

```
    if let button = self.view.viewWithTag(YOUR_TAG_HERE) as? UIBarButtonItem {
        button.enabled = false
    }
```

Comment: Cast from 'UIView?' to unrelated type 'UIBarButtonItem' always fails

Answer (score 1):

Instances of UIView have a method to find sub-views based on the tag:

```
func viewWithTag(_ tag: Int) -> UIView?
```

I'm pretty sure this will search deeply, so, as long as you can get to a view near the top of the hierarchy, this should work for you.

Comment: See k8mil's answer for disabling. It's trivially easy.

Answer (score 0):

If some one still need this:
In case where you will have `navigationController`, so you can access to your `UIBarButtonItem` like so

```
    if let barButtonItem = navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.first(where: {$0.tag == <YOUR_TAG> }) {
        // Do staff here
    }
```

and in case with `toolBar` situation is similar:

```
     if let barButtonItem = toolBar.items?.first(where: {$0.tag == <YOUR_TAG>}) {
        // Do staff here
     }
```